# return kth greatest element [ better than O(n) ]

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a stream (whose length I do not know, theoretically may be infinity).

I read the stream's elements one by one.

Every time an element is read from the stream, I want to be able to return the `k`th greatest element read so far.

(Ideally for me it would be a code in python and/or lisp/scheme).

K is read at the beginning, and K can be a NUMBER (3rd, 4th), or can be a PROCENT (K % of the total nr. of elements read so far). If K=1/2, that means to extract the median element each time... For example, after reading Nth element, it must return N/2 th greatest element

example K=1/2:

```
3 -> 3
3,4 -> 3
3,4,2 -> 3
3,4,2,1 -> 2
etc.
```

I think this example is enough to clarify the question. I need minimal possible time to extract the Kth element. (this supposes read the stream in O(1), then insert the read value , then extract the Kth element).

I want any solution better than O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you need k-th element and k is known before running the algorithm, first observation you need to store at most k elements, k smallest elements.
When you read new element you need to insert element in some datastructure keeping it's properties and having opportunity to retrieve the answer quickly.
1) You may use max-heap having at most k elements. Read element insert into heap (log(k)), then if you have more then k elements (k+1 to be precise) you need to extract_max O(log(k)) to extract and rebuild and the answer will be on the top of heap access O(1).
So, each time it takes log(k) to get k-th element, in total for all elements - n * log(k).

2) In case of using percentage, place of element will be calculated dynamically depending of how many elements were processed, here you may use order statistics tree, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree with the same log(amount of elements) insertion and log(amount of elements) lookup.

Comment: suppose k=1/2. 3->3 | 3,4 -> drop 4, and extrct 3. | 345 . In this moment I should extract 4, but I dropped it, and I cannot remember it.

Comment: if you take percentage you should store all n values. I should mention that before. In total you'll get n*log(n).

Comment: probably I will accept your answer , if I understand if order-statistic-tree solves the problem in O(log n) and O(n) space...

Comment: Basically order statistic tree is augmented self-balanced tree + additional parameter (how many childs + 1) in the node other than pointer to left, right and field for balance (color, height) whatever for self-balanced. So, it's linear space and log(n) operations.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=RHyGlha7bjE here you can get more details if interested.

Comment: you have to extract the MINIMUM value, not the maximum (hence you need a MIN-heap).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a heap containing the kth greatest elements (or a binary search tree with all elements in case of a percentage).
This gives you O(Log(k)) (or O(Log(n)) in case of a percentage).

case kth:

- if the new element is less than the min of the heap, then the kth greatest is the min of the heap.
- else replace the min of the heap by the new element and heapify, the kth greatest is the new min of the heap.

case percentage:
insert new element in a binary search tree, in such a tree, one can easily find the kth element.

Comment: in the same way I told you in my (now removed) answer: by repeatedly adding the new element and removing the smallest element in the heap when its size is above `k`. But apparently you don't like this answer.

Comment: I suppose by heapify you mean "insert into the heap". Heapify usually denotes the O(n) operation of building a heap from n elements.

Comment: to find an element into a binary search tree can take O(n). I never heard of heaps that can extract quickly Kth greatest element.

Comment: You don't extract the `k`-th greatest element, you extract the SMALLEST element from the heap! By doing so, you always have the `k` greatest element in your heap, and the lowest is exactly the `k`-th. You can prove that.

Comment: Yes, but you did not convince me that you can do it it log(n) time.

Comment: You do it in `O(log k)`. Extracting the lowest element from an heap is a standard query (and the one for which they have been conceived): if you are not sure about that bound, you can consult a whole bunch of proofs in algorithm books or in the net.

Comment: To be able to find the *k*'th smallest element in a binary search tree, you have to augment it to produce an [order statistic tree](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/OrderStatisticsTree).

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a sorted list of the *k* largest elements seen so far, you can always return the smallest in the list.  Inserting into the list is *O(k)* and getting the smallest is *O(1)*.  Since the size of the list does not depend on *n*, it is constant in terms of *n*.

Edit 2: As I said in comments below, I think a skip list may be the best bet for the list.  If I remember correctly, it has *O(log k)* time insertion, *O(1)* time for removal of the smallest element, and *O(k log k)* space (versus *O(k)* for a linked list).

Comment: But if you have a heap, inserting into the heap is O(log k), right?  The n factor comes from doing this once for each element in the stream.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that just after I posted.

Comment: I meant I thought of inserting into a heap instead of a list.  When I said "constant in terms of *n*" I meant that the insertion operation is constant because only *k* elements are stored, as opposed to storing all *n* elements.

Comment: If the heap's size never exceeds `k` (or `k+1`) then it necessarily can't have operations that scale with `n`.  Remember, you're not only inserting for each item, you are removing one as well.

Comment: keep into account that you need to store somewhere the read elements. Then , you need to compute each time the Kth greatest element, before to extract it...

Comment: Maybe a skip list is best?  *O(log k)* insertion, *O(1)* removal (but there is a memory hit).  Regardless, is the complexity worth it if *n >> k*?

Comment: O (k) is a bad time. Keep in mind that if K is a percentage, then K depends on N, so it grows all the time !

Comment: @JohnGirata: there are also heap variants with O(1) insertion and O(lg n) removal, such as pairing heaps. But since you'll be removing as often as you're inserting, asymptotically that doesn't help.

Comment: O (klogk) space looks ugly. Can we do better ?

Answer (score 0):

Heaps are decent.  O(1) lookup of minimum, O(logn) deletion.

Treaps are quite fast (nice constant) on average for this sort of problem. They allow access to (or deletion of) the least or greatest value in O(logn) time.
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/
There's a "nest" module (n best) in there that's just for this sort of thing.

Red-black trees are not blazingly fast, but they give pretty smoothly distributed performance costs, so you don't get fast-fast-fast-slow-fast-fast-fast-slow like you would with a treap.  Instead it's more like moderate-moderate-moderate-moderate.

It might be interesting to try a "Finger Tree" here.  Finger Trees purportedly give O(1) lookups of the least and greatest value in the tree.  I'm not sure about deletion.

Comment: Treaps and red-black trees are intrinsically sorted.  So to get the kth greatest, iterate in reverse - my python treap implementation allows this nicely.  When you get to the kth greatest, stop iterating.  It should be O(logn + k).

Comment: Heaps does not work so easy -- see my comment that I gave to Roman. Red-black trees are not supposed to work . If you try to convince me clearly that you can use Finger Tree in O(logn) time and O(n) space, I will chose to accept between your answer and the statistic's tree of Roman...